# Picking up an id or value from a nested ListItem in React Native Elements

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have the following for my `React Native` app:

```
<List>
        {users !== '' && 
             <FlatList
              data={users}
              keyExtractor={user => user.id}
              id={user=>user.id}
              renderItem={({user,index}) => (
                   <ListItem
                      title={`${user.lastname}, ${user.firstname}`}
                      titleStyle={{fontWeight:'bold', color:white}}
                      chevronColor={black}
                      key={index}
                      id={user.id}
                      value={user.id}
                      rightIcon={{style:{fontSize:28, color:white}}}
                      onPress={this.gotoDetail}
                      onPressRightIcon={this.gotoDetail}
                    />
                  )}
                />
            }
 </List>
```

I want to pick up the **user id** and thus this is my event handler

```
gotoDetail=(e)=>(
 //Tried all below but no success
 console.log(e.target.value)
 console.log(e.target.id)
 console.log(this.id)
 console.log(this.value)
)
```

Also tried to pass a value from `onPress` event

```
onPress={this.gotoDetail(user.id)}
```

And the event handler

```
gotoDetail=(userId)=>(
  console.log(userId)
)
```

Also to no avail.

I also tried to use `refs` but still to no avail.

Comment: How does the `ListItem` component look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put it that way

```
gotoDetail = (e, user) => {
    // access user from here
}

<ListItem
    ...
    onPressRightIcon={(e) => this.gotoDetail(e, user)}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks Tareq. GOD bless.

Answer (score 3):

You need to close over the value from the parent scope rather than execute `gotoDetail` inline. The following should work.

```
onPress={() => this.gotoDetail(user.id)}
```

Subsequently calling `gotoDetail` should receive the expected argument.

```
gotoDetail={(userId)=>(
  console.log(userId)
)}
```